# Multiple List with Tabs

Tags: react-admin

Is there a way to create multiple List in a same item selected from the sidebar.

Like a way to implement full React Admin datagrid with data fetched from API (react Query, axios, ...), not from the URL from name or DataProvider[image]

Comment: <List> component takes data from URL, but <Datagrid>, <SimpleList> can be used for your purpose in react-admin. For more info: [see](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html).